# Instagram direct message link

Tags: html, web, instagram

Is there a way to use href in a link within an anchor so that people can send a direct message on my instagram page from my website as it is done with whatsapp?

Eg:

makes the whatsapp icon have a clickable link through which messages can be sent to the whatsapp number specified.

Comment: Wrong tags used and unclear. Please improve and add details to your question.

Comment: I have edited it. Hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: It's not possible. The way you describe WhatsApp works is explained by a behaviour of android to choose in which app to open a phone link, in the case of Instagram well there is no phone number, only a link to Instagram. Now you can link directly to the page of an user but not to the dm of this user. Unless they add the functionality themselves